# How can I hide this imperfection in wood joint?

Tags: wood, woodworking, joints, mdf, wood-filler

I am working on making wood panel for one of my wall ( I made this wood panel using prined mdf ). All the wood joints are not that much noticable except two. I used wood filler in all joints including these to make these less noticeable. But no matter what I do I am not able to hide/smooth these two joints.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Just in case, all these woods are primed mdf.

**Front view:**
[image]

**Close-up/Side view:**
[image]

Comment: To hide it, since I am guessing you don't want redo it, will need to fill in the space and feather it out 6 or 12 inches.  Top joint might need to do in layers and build up.

Comment: `need to fill in the space and feather` , how to do this? wood filler + sanding? Or is there some other better way?

Comment: Lightly sand the paint on there now so that the filler can bind better, then fill in and use a straight edge to remove excess and sand smooth.  Want a very slight ramp so both edges match together.  A long ramp(8 to 12 inches) will be hard to see, A 4 to 6 inch might be okay also.

Comment: Might also be able to glue a wood shim to it, cut it to length where it matches the height.  They are usually cheap in a brunch, so you can try a few.  Use a little filler to smooth out the thin end to the wood.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying wood filler + sanding. If that doesn't work I will try wood shim.

Comment: As noted, heavy sanding on the high spots. Be sure to prime with an oil (not water) based primer, as raw mdf will swell and you'll be back to the starting problem.

Comment: How about for the plank on the right, separate the wood from the backboard with a tool like a chisel or something hammed vertically up under. Peel the right plank up a bit and put small wedges under it until the right plank is level with the left plank. Then fill under the raised plank where the now-gap is, and paint touch up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would sand the horizontal trim at the top down until it meets the diagonal trim. You'll want to extend the sanding horizontally to make a smooth transition from "full thickness" at the good joint to the left to "reduced thickness" where these two pieces meet. This will help hide the difference in thickness.

Once that's done, I would sand the paint off the horizontal trim to the right of the big gap (which will now be much thinner) for 6-12" to the right, then build it up with thin layers of wood filler to make a smooth transition up to the joint where the current mismatch is.

You'll end up with your thickest piece of horizontal trim at the left end of the "V", then a gradual thinning to the right end of the "V" (due to the initial sanding), and a further thinning to a point mid-way or so to the next diagonal piece (due to the wood filler). By making the transitions slowly over many inches, they will be very difficult to notice by eye.

Once you've got it nice, smooth and matching to your satisfaction, clean up all the sawdust and repaint according to your original paint schedule.